# cx_oracle's executemany with batcherros=True not working as expected

Tags: python, cx-oracle

**Goal**: Want to catch invalid row data(NULL for one of the columns) by using batcherrors=True, and check them using cursor.getbatcherrors().

**Expecting** : Invalid row data should be put into getbatcherrors() and all valid rows should be inserted.

**Actual**: empty getbatcherrors() and exit from the execution

**Error Message** : Type error Expecting Number

**What I've tried** : execute(statement, record),
this gives expected error message, **CAN NOT INSERT NULL**. Since I want to insert in bulk i'm trying to use executemany but it exit the execution when invalid insertion found.

Comment: the title tells that you used `executemany` while the part *what you have tried* tells `execute` ..?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I've first tried execute() to insert the record one after another. But it's taking so much time for the bulk insert  then I shifted to executemany(batcherrors=True). But the problem here is  'invalid row insertion causes all the rows to be discarded from the insertion'. I don't see batcherrors=True is working as expected.

Comment: `code` names = ','.join(target_columns.keys())

        bind_variables = ','.join([':' + x for x in target_columns.keys()])

        sql_insert = f"INSERT INTO {target_tb_name}({names}) VALUES({bind_variables})"

        # cursor.prepare(sql_insert)

        try:

            cursor.executemany(sql_insert, data_list, batcherrors=True)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e) #gives, 'expecting a number'
            print(cursor.getbatcherrors()) # gives []